# Presenting MFMailComposeViewController, but it disappears right after it's visible

Tags: iphone, ios, ios5

The first ViewController in my app subclasses UIImagePickerController and then through the didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo callback, I do the following:

```
EditViewController *editViewController = [[EditViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"EditViewController" bundle:nil];
[self pushViewController:editViewController animated:YES];
```

this ViewController displays properly... Then, through an IBAction, I do the following:

```
PreviewViewController *previewViewController = [[PreviewViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"PreviewViewController" bundle:nil];
previewViewController.tempImage = img;
[self.navigationController pushViewController:previewViewController animated:YES];
```

This view also displays correctly. In this VC I'm trying to use the **MFMailComposeViewController** for sending an email. When I attempt to push it, I get **Pushing a navigation controller is not supported**:

```
MFMailComposeViewController *mailViewController = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];
mailViewController.mailComposeDelegate = self;
[mailViewController setSubject:@"Subject Goes Here."];
[mailViewController setMessageBody:@"Your message goes here." isHTML:NO];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:mailViewController animated:YES];
```

But when I present it instead:

```
[self presentModalViewController:mailViewController animated:YES];
```

The mailViewController appears for only a second and then disappears and I see a black background (but not the previous VC's view) with an empty navbar on top.  The app is still running at this point.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Does this issue only show on a phone that is not an iPhone 5?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you still want to push the mailViewController you can do this (iOS 7 only):

```
UIViewController *theMailViewController = [[mailViewController viewControllers] lastObject];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:theMailViewController animated:YES];
```

That way the MailViewController's rootViewController will get pushed into your actual navigationController.

I hope this helps you.

Comment: Pushing mailViewController hiding navigation bar of mailViewController ie Save and Cancel button is not visible.

Comment: not working, at least in iOs8: all I get is an unresponsive view (can't change the contents (body, title, to, etc), and the upper "cancel"/"save" buttons are, respectively, unresponsive and disabled).

Comment: That's correct, @Rick77 this won't work for iOS 8. Apple doesn't let you present the mail composer in any other way than modally.

Comment: taking back the -1: thank you for updating the answer :)

Comment: So I already have a modal dialog up, and the last step is to send the email. So I want that pushed onto my presented stack. As @rick77 said, I get an unresponsive VC. So should I present a modal on top of another modal? Dismiss the current and show another? All this seems kinda goofy and the best thing IMO is to push onto the current modal dialog. Any ideas?

Comment: @Rob Hi, it's been a while since the last time I have dealt with the issue, but if I where you I would stick to the standard paradigm (not that you have other choices...): you can present the mail view controller on top of the other and, as soon as the mail is sent, intercept the delegate method to dismiss the first modal without an animation. The devil is in the details, of course, but this is the road I'll chose if I where in you.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I ended up dismissing the current modal, showing the mail modal, and when that one is dismissed, I don't bring up the previous modal again. The biggest question for me was whether or not to animate it (as you pointed out). If I didn't, I would see it dissappear and then appear (it wouldn't look like it just changed, you would actually see the "nothing" step in between), so I ended up animating. The animation is goofy, but I found a few other apps that do it this way. Thanks again for your input!